# How to locally change the DNS tool in Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, dns

I need to force my PC with Windows XP as if there were a DNS record on my domain, a `CNAME` record for paths with the value `ghs.google.com`.

How can I do that?

The DNS is cached somewhere between me and the domain's DNS server, and I need to test the settings.

I could get the IP of `ghs.google.com` and put it in my hosts file for `s.example.com` – but is there any command line option for that?

Comment: Batchfile anyone?

Comment: I was afraid I need to restart browser after editing hostfile, it's not so. So it is no big of a deal. In fact I can probably create my own batch fle to edit the host file

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a good command line tool for directly editing DNS resolution in Windows. I think the hosts file is going to be your best bet.